# Matching a number preceeded by a know string, followed by an unknown number of characters

Tags: c#, regex

`[SOME_WORDS:200:1000]`

Trying to match just the last `1000` part. Both numbers are variable and can contain an unknown number of characters (although they are expected to contain digits, I cannot rule out that they may also contain other characters). The SOME_WORDS part is known and does not change.

So I begin by doing a positive lookbehind for `[SOME_WORDS:` followed by a positive lookahead for the trailing `]`

That gives us the pattern `(?<=\[SOME_WORDS:).*(?=])`

 And captures the part `200:1000`

Now because I don't know how many characters are after `SOME_WORDS:`, but I know that it ends with another `:` I use `.*:` to indicate any character any amount of time followed by `:`

That gives us the pattern `(?<=\[SOME_WORDS:.*:).*(?=])`

However at this point the pattern no longer matches anything and this is where I become confused. What am I doing wrong here?

If I assume that the first number will always be 3 characters long I can replace `.*` with `...` to get the pattern `(?<=\[SOME_WORDS:...:).*(?=])` and this correctly captures just the `1000` part. However I don't understand why replacing `...` with `.*` makes the pattern not capture anything.

EDIT:
It seems like the online tool I was using to test the regex pattern wasn't working correctly. The pattern `(?<=\[SOME_WORDS:.*:).*(?=])` matches the `1000` with no issues when actually done in .net

Comment: to answer simply, no.

Comment: Why not just do this: `\[SOME_WORDS:\d+:(\d+)\]`? Or even this if you cannot guarantee the numbers are numbers: `\[SOME_WORDS:.+:(.+)\]`

Comment: @Garry you could try this `(?<=\[SOME_WORDS:[^:]*:).*(?=])`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Not sure that's valid regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You usually cannot use a `+` or a `*` in a lookbehind, only in a lookahead.
If c# does allow these than you could use a `.*?` instead of a `.*` as the `.*` will eat the second `:`

Try this:
`(?<=\[SOME_WORDS:)(?=\d+:(\d+)])`
The match wil be in the first capture group

Quote from http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

> The bad news is that most regex flavors do not allow you to use just any regex inside a lookbehind, because they cannot apply a regular expression backwards. The regular expression engine needs to be able to figure out how many characters to step back before checking the lookbehind. When evaluating the lookbehind, the regex engine determines the length of the regex inside the lookbehind, steps back that many characters in the subject string, and then applies the regex inside the lookbehind from left to right just as it would with a normal regex.

Answer (score 2):

As Robert Smit mentions this is due to the `*` being a greedy operator. Greedy operators consume as many characters as they possibly can when they are matched first. They only give up characters if the match fails. If you make the greedy operator lazy(`*?`), then matching consumes as little number of characters as possible for the match to succeed, so the `:` is not consumed by `*.` You can also use `[^:]*` which is match any character other than `:`.